# Where is the radiator cap of my car?

Tags: suzuki, maruti

I have a 2011 make Maruti Suzuki Ritz LDi (Diesel). I'm attaching a photograph of the engine bay here. Where is the radiator cap located in this picture? How to measure the coolant level? Also, what are the caps in the circles?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radiator cap to top up the coolant is just to the right of the battery.

The item in a red circle top left is not a cap but a braking valve (most likely) or abs unit (possibly) - either way don’t try and remove it : it is not just a “cap”.

The item in red at the bottom is one of the A/C charging or access ports - do not open it unless you have the equipment - I have not looked for the other port, but it will be there.

Edit based on comment: the connection to the radiator - bottom right of the image is so close to the top of the radiator that a separate filling cap is not necessary - but  it may cause a slower filling time, but that will depend on where the other pipe from the expansion tank goes and its size so it may not be an issue at all.

WARNING: cooling systems are pressurised when hot, make sure it is cold before removing caps or undoing pipes.

Comment: So basically, there is no pressure cap on top of the radiator as I have seen in other cars. Rather, the overflow/extension tank is used for coolant top-up as well.

Comment: The overflow/expansion tank is pressurized. Do not open it while the system is hot

Comment: @mikes so important I’ll borrow it and add...